# two charts inside md-card with same height

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have two charts inside the md-cards container (angular-material). They both have a flex property of flex='33', which means they have the same width. However, I want that they have the same height too.

My code right now:

*html*:

```
<div id="surveyStats" layout="row" layout-wrap layout-align="center center">
    <md-card flex="33">
      <md-card-title>
        <md-card-title-text>
          <h4>Examples Collected For Each Intent</h4>
          <canvas id="examplesIntent"></canvas>
        </md-card-title-text>
      </md-card-title>
    </md-card>
    <md-card flex="33">
      <md-card-title>
        <md-card-title-text>
          <h4>Intents Covered in Survey</h4>
          <div class="intent-result">
            <div id="intentsCovered" layout="row" layout-align="center center"></div>
          </div>
        </md-card-title-text>
      </md-card-title>
    </md-card>
  </div>
```

*css*:

```
#surveyStats {
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.intent-result{
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

I additionally add a screenshot of these two charts. Can someone please tell me how to set them to the same height (without doing that in px, I would prefer a method similar to the flex='33' option. )

[image: Screenshot of md-cards charts]

Answer (score 0):

Can't really reproduce this but try

```
#surveyStats {
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: flex;
}
```